# zsh fail to expand apt-get regex?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, debian, regex, zsh

zsh seems to fail expand `apt-get` regular expression. For instance I would like to install all packages that has the prefix `llvm-3.1`, and I use:

```
sudo apt-get install llvm-3.1*
```

But zsh tells me that:

```
zsh: no matches found: llvm-3.1*
```

zsh expands other regrex well(`ls *` would always list `all` no-hidden files in the current directory).

I also tried `bash` or even `sh`(which is actually `dash`), and they both work right.

SO do I need to set some additional options to make *zsh* work for apt-get? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Those patterns are not regexps, they're commonly referred to as glob patterns. 
And in no case will the shell correctly expand glob patterns for package names 
to be used with apt-get. Shells will only expand glob patterns based on files 
that are present on your local file system.

The other shells that you've used also fail to expand that pattern, but rather 
than reporting an error they pass on the argument as typed to apt-get which 
then is able to match the pattern itself and do so against the names of 
available packages. You can get that behavior from zsh by using:

```
unsetopt no_match
```

But it would be better to get used to quoting special characters like `*` when 
you do not want those patterns to be expanded by the shell. If you happened to 
have a file which matched that pattern in your current directory when running 
that command any of those shells would expand the pattern to match that file 
before running apt-get, this is unlikely to give the results that you are 
expecting.

Any of the following would work in any of those shells, even if you have files 
which match the pattern:

```
sudo apt-get install llvm-3.1\*
sudo apt-get install 'llvm-3.1*'
sudo apt-get install "llvm-3.1*"
```

That would prevent the shell from trying to incorrectly expand the pattern, and 
for zsh it will avoid the error message if the pattern cannot be expanded.

Comment: Thanks for your answers. And sorry that I used the wrong words; I should have noted that `*`, `?` etc. in Bash are also referred to glob.

Comment: So how do you like the strategy that zsh used by default(report error message rather than pass this `llvm-3.1*` to apt-get)? I feel that it is not so friendly.

Comment: Another possibility is to prepend the command with `noglob`, hence `noglob sudo apt-get install llvm-3.1*` should work as intended. You can define an alias for often used commands with wildcards, e.g. `alias scp="noglob scp"`, if you don't what to change the behavior globally. (But alias won't work with sudo I suppose...)

Comment: I prefer that the shell report problems to me rather than silently continuing on with an interpretation that may not match what I had intended, so I much prefer the zsh handling of that.